# Repaint() or Revalidate() won't work in my code

Tags: java, swing

thank you for helping me.

I'm making random panel generator.
first, user chooses what shape to draw and my code randomly draw 1~10 shapes on `JFrame`.
Next, user can choose Kth panel and change its color.

But, here's the problem: Once it added to `JFrame`, it won't change color.

for example, if I change 1st shape color to red and show it, its color change to red. But I change 1st shape color to blue, it won't change.

Before show it, its color changes well if I don't show it on `JFrame`.

I discovered that I can solve this by making a new application each time before showing it, but My purpose is to use only one `JFrame`.

Here's my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shapes
{
    private class TransparentPanel extends JPanel
    {
        {
            setOpaque(false);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        enginePart();
    }
    static void enginePart()
    {
        JFrame application= new JFrame();
        btnConstructor makeBtn = new btnConstructor();
        makeShapes panel = new makeShapes(0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        randomNumMemorize memorizeIt = new randomNumMemorize();
        Random getRandomNum = new Random();
        int[] thirdChoice = new int[2], KthShapeCntField = new int[10000];
        int memorizeItArr[][][] = new int[10000][25][10];
        //3차원 배열을 선언하여 저장. 1번째 칸에는 도형의 코드, 2번째 칸에는 k번째 도형의 각각 갯수, 3번째 칸에는 k번째 도형의 정보를 담습니다.
        int makeItCnt, thirdChoiceOfK, thirdChoiceOfColor;
        int applicationWidth=500, applicationHeight=500, choiceCnt=0;
        application.setSize(applicationWidth, applicationHeight);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        while(true)
        {
            int first_choice = makeBtn.optionBtn();
            //입력하기, 색깔바꾸기, 종료하기 중 하나 선택
            if(first_choice==0)
            {//입력하기 선택
                int secondChoice = makeBtn.drawSelected();//사용자 도형 설정
                makeItCnt = getRandomNum.nextInt(9)+1;//생성할 도형 개수 지정
                KthShapeCntField[choiceCnt] = makeItCnt;
                for(int i=0;i<makeItCnt;i++)
                {
                    memorizeItArr[choiceCnt][i] = memorizeIt.randomNumMemorize(secondChoice, 0);
                }
                choiceCnt+=1;
                //k번째 도형 == choiceCnt
                continue;
            }
            else if(first_choice==1)
            {//k번째 도형 색깔 바꾸기 선택
                System.out.println("==============REDRAW!!================");
                thirdChoice = makeBtn.changeColorSelected();//k 선택부
                thirdChoiceOfK = thirdChoice[0] - 1;//콤퓨타는 0부터 세니까 여기서 1 빼줍니다.
                thirdChoiceOfColor = thirdChoice[1];
                int temp= thirdChoiceOfK, i=0;
                if(thirdChoiceOfK == -1 || thirdChoiceOfColor==-1) continue;
                while(temp-KthShapeCntField[i]>=0)
                {
                    temp-=KthShapeCntField[i++];
                }
                memorizeItArr[i][temp][5] = thirdChoiceOfColor;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {//추가동작 선택
                /*JFrame application= new JFrame();
                application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                application.setSize(500,500);*/
                int fourthChoice = makeBtn.additionalActionSelected();
                if(fourthChoice==0)
                {//도형 숨기기
                    hide(panel, application, applicationWidth, applicationHeight);
                    continue;
                }
                else if(fourthChoice==1)
                {//도형 보이기
                    int temp=0;
                    application.revalidate();
                    application.repaint();
                    for(int i=0;i<choiceCnt;i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0; j<KthShapeCntField[i]; j++)
                        {
                            panel = new makeShapes(choiceCnt, memorizeItArr[i][j][0], memorizeItArr[i][j][1], memorizeItArr[i][j][2], memorizeItArr[i][j][3], memorizeItArr[i][j][4], memorizeItArr[i][j][5]);
                            panel.validate();
                            panel.repaint();
                            application.add(panel);
                            panel.setOpaque(false);//투명화
                            System.out.printf("%dth Shape color is: %d\n",temp++, memorizeItArr[i][j][5]);
                            application.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {//종료
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void hide(makeShapes panel, JFrame application, int width, int height)
    {
        panel = new makeShapes(-1,100,0,0,width,height,100);
        application.add(panel);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
class makeShapes extends JPanel
{
    private int choice, x, y, size1, size2;
    private int color=0, cnt;// 0:red, 1:green, 2:blue, 3:yellow, 4:purple 5:black
    public makeShapes(int cnt, int choice, int x, int y, int size1, int size2, int usrColor)
    {
        this.choice = choice;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size1 = size1;
        this.size2 = size2;
        this.color = usrColor;
        this.cnt = cnt;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        String s_cnt = Integer.toString(this.cnt);
        switch(color)
        {
            case 100:
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case 1:
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                break;
            case 2:
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                break;
            case 3:
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                break;
            case 4:
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                break;
            case 5: case 0:
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;
        }
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 100:
                g.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
                break;
            case 0:
                g.drawOval(x, y, size1, size2);
                break;
            case 1:
                g.drawRect(x, y, size1, size2);
                break;
            case 2:
                g.drawLine(x,y, x+size1, x+size2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
class randomNumMemorize
{
    Random getRandom = new Random();
    private int choice, x, y, size1, size2, cnt;
    private int color=1;
    public int[] randomNumMemorize(int usrchoice, int usrcolor)
    {
        this.choice = usrchoice;
        this.x = getRandom.nextInt(400);
        this.y = getRandom.nextInt(400);
        this.size1 = getRandom.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.size2 = getRandom.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.color = usrcolor;
        int[] retArr = {choice, x, y, size1, size2, color};
        return retArr;
    }
}
```

```
class btnConstructor
{
    public int optionBtn()
    {
        String btn_msg[] = {"Draw Shapes", "Change Color", "Additional Action"};
        int num = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Choose what you want.","User choice",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,btn_msg,"Draw Shapes");
        return num;
    }
    public int drawSelected()
    {
        String btn_msg[] = {"Circle", "Rectangle", "Line"};
        int num = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Choose your shape","Shape choice",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,btn_msg,"Circle");
        return num;
    }
    public int[] changeColorSelected()
    {
        int choiceOfK, choiceOfColor;
        String numOfK = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number that you want to change color");
        String numOfColor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which Color do you prefer?\nRed:1 Green:2  Blue:3  Yellow:4  Black:5");
        if(numOfK==null || numOfColor==null) choiceOfK = choiceOfColor=-1;
        else {
            choiceOfK = Integer.parseInt(numOfK);
            choiceOfColor = Integer.parseInt(numOfColor);
        }
        int[] return_it = {choiceOfK, choiceOfColor};
        return return_it;
    }
    public int additionalActionSelected()
    {
        String btn_msg[] = {"Hide", "Show", "Exit"};
        int num = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Choose your action","User choice",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,btn_msg,"Restore");
        return num;
    }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
application.revalidate();
application.repaint();
```

Comment: 1) Class names should start with a upper case character. 2) The Color of the object should be a property of your custom class. When you use a JLabel you use the setText(...) method to change the text of the label. Well, the same design applies to your class. If you want to change the Color you invoke a `setColor(...)` method on your component. The `setColor(...)` method will then save the color as a property of the class and then invoke repaint().

Comment: 3) A GUI should not have while (true) logic. A GUI is event driven. The new shape color should be changed based on some user action. 4) I don't understand your logic but I would comment you should NOT keep creating new components. You should only create your components at the start. If you want to change the color, then you update the existing component instead of trying to create a new one. 5) There is no need to invoke revalidate(). That method is only used if you create an add a new component to a visible frame.

Comment: Thankyou for Advice. As you recommend, I revise my code and It worked.
I moved draw section to paintComponent().
You can see my code here:
https://github.com/BUZZINGPolarBear/Kau_2020_AutomnSemester/blob/main/Shapes.java
I really appreciate you.